# motherboard issues - WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

Tags: motherboard

I have been getting some WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR errors with BSOD recently. Along those lines, I think something is wrong with my motherboard's wi-fi / blutooth adapter. It keeps losing wifi connection. I had to disable blutooth via Windows 10 settings. The pc was built in Dec 2015.

So far, I tried updating drivers, and disabling wifi and blutooth adapter via device manager. It didn't help BSOD.

I am thinking about replacing the motherboard. It is a MSI Extreme Gaming Intel X99 LGA 2011.

Is it possible to keep everything else and just replace the board with another LGA 2011 based board? Should I try a new wifi / blutooth adapter to see if it helps? I am not sure how I would disable the onboard wifi / blutooth adapter. It is Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC-7260.

The OS is on C drive, SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 1TB SATA III 3D NAND Internal Solid State Drive. I have all my software installed on D drive, WD Black 3TB Performance Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 7200 RPM SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch.

If I replace the board, will I be able to keep my software on D drive? I assume I will have to do a clean windows install on C.

These are the things I would like to keep :

- Intel Core i7-5930K - Core i7 5th Gen Haswell-E 6-Core 3.5 GHz LGA 2011-v3 140W Desktop Processor
- Corsair Hydro Series H100i GTX Extreme Performance Water / Liquid CPU Cooler. 240mm
- CORSAIR Dominator Platinum 64GB (4 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2400 (PC4 19200) Desktop Memory
- EVGA SuperNOVA 1600 G2 120-G2-1600-X1 80+ GOLD 1600W Fully Modular Power Supply
- 3 x EVGA GeForce GTX 980 Ti 06G-P4-4996-KR 6GB FTW GAMING w/ACX 2.0+  Graphics Card

Any thoughts? suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post online some `.dmp` files from `C:\Windows\Minidump`.

Comment: @harrymc logs added.

Comment: I meant posting online (OneDrive, Dropbox) the `.dmp` files from `C:\Windows\Minidump`, not this text. Better zip up the files.

Comment: @harrymc   https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9xfchsvp4pu5ki/Minidump.7z?dl=0

Comment: You had some error - the file has only 93 bytes.

Comment: @harrymc  added again. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ocoofq4yprlpweh/AAB_HWQnID11ONhcxUQp8ApKa?dl=0

Comment: WHEA stands for "Windows Hardware Error Architecture". You might have a hardware error. I suggest to first follow the advice in [this article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/disk-recovery/0x00000124.html). If no solution is found, then run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight.

Comment: @harrymc yeah, that is a simple google result. your link does not provide any help either.

Comment: You have a hardware error, so tests are needed to find where, or at least where not. It's fine with me if you don't want to do this and prefer to blindly replace hardware. I'm finished here.

Comment: Also... OT...  but just curious to why 3 GPUs? I'm almost certain the 980TI didn't do SLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rules of elimination in case somebody else comes across this post. I already debugged driver updates, Windows updates, disabling some devices and so on before posting this question. Removed the win debugs btw since there was no help in there.

SOLUTION: disabled wifi adapter and blutooth on the motherboard. Purchased a $30 usb 3.0 driven wifi / blutooth adapter. Not only my speed increase previously around 20-30 mbps download, I also love the convenience factor.

speedtest:
DOWNLOAD Mbps
142.98
UPLOAD Mbps
149.13

Another note, this board is utter garbage : MSI Computer EATX (Extended ATX) DDR4 3000 LGA 2011-3 Computer Motherboards X99A XPOWER AC. I am already on my 3rd board and there is no more warranty left.

Hope this will give me a few more years. thanks for checking my answer. Cheers.

Comment: Some boards have these cards on a 'module' that's actually a break out for a 'normal' PCIe or mini pci-e card. If you're annoyed/bored enough, It might be possible to swap out the mini pci-e or m.2 adaptor hiding inside what looks like a plug in 'non standard' module